# Get directory of raster from PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, raster

I am currently testing the functionality of raster in Postgis. I have found the option of creating "register" (or out-db) tables in PostGIS, which link to the rasterfile outside the database, using the ´-R´ flag:

```
raster2pgsql -R C:\Temp\raster_test\DSM_01_test.tif test.dsm_01_test| psql.....
```

As far as I understand it the PostgreSQL/PostGIS table does not store the raster file itself - only metadata is stored.
As the [documentation](https://postgis.net/docs/using_raster_dataman.html) states it:

> Only the metadata of the raster and path location to the raster is stored in the database (not the pixels)

with my out-db raster table`test.dsm_01_test`, how do I get the path of the rasterfile from the PostGIS database?

I have tried the table `raster_columns`, but it doesn't hold the path to the rasterfile.

Answer (score 2):

Having re-read [Chapter 9](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_reference.html#outdb), I found [st_bandpath](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_BandPath.html) to do exactly what I was looking for:

```sql
SELECT st_bandpath(rast) 
FROM test.dsm_01_test
```

returns

```
| st_bandpath                           |
| text                                  |
|---------------------------------------|
| C:\Temp\raster_test\dsm_01_test.tif   |
| ....                                  |
```